# Stability of origin of dynamical system

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, dynamical-systems

Usually you can note some nice structure in the problem which enables construction of a nice Lyapunov function. But this one is just a monster. Maybe there is a trick I've missed?

*Investigate the stability of the origin of the following system.*

$$x' = yx - 5x^3 \\
y' = x^2 - 5y$$

**Attempt:** 
First note that the are no other fixed points. Also note that linearization will fail at the origin.

We try some Lyapunov function $V(x,y) = G(x) + H(y)$ which gives

$$V' = g(x)xy - g(x)5x^3 + h(y)x^2-h(y)5y$$

I can not figure out what kind of function would make $V'$ definite in either direction, due to the differences in order. I should also note that I've already caught a lot of sloppy errors in these exam questions, making the problems either impossible to solve or something other than the posted solution. This particular problem has no solutions posted, however.

Comment: Not sure I am following... but the simplest function in this context $V(x,y)=x^2+y^2$ yields, using $2x^2y\leqslant x^4+y^2$, $v(t)=V(x(t),y(t))$,, $v'(t)=4x^2(t)y(t)-10x^4(t)-10y^2(t)\leqslant-8x^4(t)-8y^2(t)$ hence $v'(t)<0$ everywhere except at $(x(t),y(t))=(0,0)$. What more does one need?

Comment: Well, say $V' = 2x^2y - 5x^4-5y^2$ equivalently, then for small enough |x| to neglect the $x^4$ term, we have roughly $2x^2y - 5y^2 = y(2x^2-5y)$. if $0 < 5y < 2x^2$, then the term is positive. If $0 < 2x^2 < 5y$, then it is negative.

Comment: ?? Please exhibit **one** couple of values $(x,y)$ such that $2x^2y-5x^4-5y^2>0$.

Comment: I trust you, but I'm not sure how you arrived at it...

Comment: Trust is really really offtopic here. Following closely each step in my first comment would be more useful. What is the first one you have problems with, already?

Comment: The inequality $2x^2y \leq x^4 + y^2$.

Comment: Right. Did you try to prove it? Say you consider the RHS minus the LHS. Write it on a piece of paper and put it in front of you. Any idea why this is always nonnegative?

Comment: Ah. $x^2 = u$, then completing the square. Should have seen that I guess. Thank you for your help.